# Exclude "I" and "O" from alpha-numeric id in stringi character set

Tags: r, regex, stringi, character-class

I know from [Generate unique alphanumeric IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652356/generate-unique-alphanumeric-ids), that I can use `stringi` and `stri_rand_strings` to generate a unique alpha-numeric id.  I am trying to figure out an efficient way to do so but only include the numbers 0-9 and all letters but "I" and "O".  I can't seem to figure out how to include this in the pattern `c( LETTERS[c(1:8,10:14,16:26)],"[0-9]")`

```
stri_rand_strings(25, 6)
```

Comment: `pattern` argument has to be one character set (between surrounding `[...]`), you can't concatenate multiple sets with `[A-H][0-9]` as you're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify the pattern to exclude those letters

```
stri_rand_strings(25, 6, pattern = "[a-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]")

[1] "l3e6eH" "NfcjuP" "vtHxWy" "bs2Zd1" "2UGWoJ" "GhettL" "mvvLqi" "AtBBnd" "ijsDFj" "4CXpn6" "MpyUEh" "HZUyDi" "Fba7Af"
[14] "M3lWdn" "A5Vf8D" "tcC9as" "jTXyK5" "U5gUCy" "rnQN1p" "vEouUF" "c8ZU35" "C91o7m" "vuM7iE" "dl49kM" "opucvl"
```

To only use capital letters

```
stri_rand_strings(25, 6, pattern = "[A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]")
```

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible approach is to use [ICU regex engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) feature called [*character class subtraction*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html).

To match any ASCII alphanumeric chars except `I` and `O` use a `[[:alnum:]&\p{ASCII}-[IO]]` regex pattern:

- `[` - start of the bracket expression:

  - `[:alnum:]` - match any Unicode alphanumeric
  - `&` - AND
  - `\p{ASCII}` - the alphanumeric must be from the ASCII set
  - `-[IO]` - but `I` and `O` chars
- `]` - end of the bracket expression.

The final solution will look like

```
stri_rand_strings(25, 6, pattern = "[[:alnum:]&\\p{ASCII}-[IO]]")
```

Output I got:

```
[1] "7hWJdu" "cjvekt" "oPqg0C" "pK1JRi" "lrjB2G" "2Zjp0P" "bR7XcK" "V1i8XG" "hojuMU" "4fHpAP" "vSAHFP" "BTXabM" "RWQjaF" "Ac0VbH" "d4GXh1" "kAXWR5" "gx7rQX" "sRXmmw"
[19] "kXcb9H" "mJPuCL" "yBylmm" "wqCtUJ" "zgefj9" "1v6gYY" "l47wjf"
```